# Multiple ssh jump in iTerm2

Tags: ssh, iterm2, bastion-host

I have few ssh host, like host_A, host_B and host_C.
To connect to host_C, I have to ssh to host_A, then ssh to host_B (host_A and B are jump server), then finally ssh to host_C.

Does iterm2 support jump server setting? Or this can only be done using script? (Or, is there a recommended GUI ssh client?)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "command" parameter of the profile for a connection, you can use the `-J` parameter of the `ssh` command to use a jump host. From `ssh`s [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J):

> -J *destination*
>
> Connect to the target host by first making an ssh connection to the jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there. Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters. This is a shortcut to specify a **ProxyJump** configuration directive. Note that configuration directives supplied on the command-line generally apply to the destination host and not any specified jump hosts. Use *~/.ssh/config* to specify configuration for jump hosts.

This means you can also specify multiple jumps in a row.

I would recommend that you first try the jumps and configuration on a plain login shell with a manually entered `ssh` command, and once you found the combination you are happy with, create an iTerm2 profile with that.

Comment: An untested example (and therefore not in the answer): `ssh -J hostA,hostB hostC` - notice that the final host (hostC) is not part of the `-J` parameters!